# Uncaught (in promise): [object Window] at resolvePromise

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I've just picked up a new code base (Angular8), and I get this error when running unit tests.

> ERROR: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Window]
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Window]
> at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:797:1)
> at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:754:1)
> at http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:858:1
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:391:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:339:1)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:390:1)
> at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:168:1)
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:559:1)
> at invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:469:1)

I have no idea which of the 500+ unit tests are failing.   The stack trace doesn't mention any user code.  Where do I look?  Are there other ways of running the tests (I use `ng test`) that will give more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[karma-mocha-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter) would help you. It prints out the console logs before the expectations results. In this way, you can easily track which console message (including the error messages) was printed by each test.

Comment: Not sure if it's because it's not compatible with Angular8, but after installing and configuring, I get an error 'Can not load reporter "mocha", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?'

Comment: seems like instruction missing a step
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        plugins: [
            ...
            require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
        ],

Comment: Well, that's narrowed it down to the failing test.  Unfortunately, it doesn't give any more info about what the problem is.

Comment: sure. I believe the questions `Where do I look? Are there other ways of running the tests (I use ng test) that will give more information?` are answered (: if you would ask questions with the details of the narrowed down failing test, the SO community would help you as well (: